# Letters after regex in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I was reviewing some code and I found this regex in the Ruby code: `/#\s?\z/n`. Could anyone explain me what the `n` after the regex means? Are there more special letters that you can put after the regex and if so, what are their meaning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Encoding](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Encoding):

> Regular expressions are assumed to use the source encoding. This can be overridden with one of the following modifiers.

```
/pat/u - UTF-8
/pat/e - EUC-JP
/pat/s - Windows-31J
/pat/n - ASCII-8BIT
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can put letters *(modifiers)* after the regular expression and they are considered as [options](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html#label-Options), or to be more exact [modifiers](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html#label-Options) which are passed to the regular expression engine to alter its behavior such as match case insensitively, or support Unicode sequences ... etc.

In your situation: [n: ASCII-8BIT encoding support](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html#label-Encoding).

In other words: Assume the text is encoded in 8-bit ASCII and use the same encoding for the characters in the regular expression.